# "python -m idlelib.idle" not working - Windows 10

Tags: python, terminal, python-idle, python-venv, python-3.10

I'm running *Python 3.10.2288.0* (x64) on a *Windows 10* OS.
I use IDLE as interpreter.

So far, I have been running IDLE (in and out *venv*) by:

```
C:path\to\venv venv\Scripts\Activate
(venv) C:path\to\venv python -m idlelib.idle
```

All of a sudden, this command didn't work anymore.
The following error appeared:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\idlelib\idle.py", line 13, in <module>
    from idlelib.pyshell import main  # This is subject to change
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\idlelib\pyshell.py", line 53, in <module>
    from idlelib import debugger
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\idlelib\debugger.py", line 7, in <module>
    from idlelib import macosx
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\idlelib\macosx.py", line 7, in <module>
    from test.support import requires, ResourceDenied
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test'
```

I tried to reinstall Python, but nothing changed.
The same error appears when running command outside the *venv*.
It seems that everything is up-to-date.

What do you suggest?

Thanks,
idromv

Comment: Please include the full error traceback, not just the last line

Comment: Also you will need to delete and re-create all virtual environments after re-installing python

Comment: Thanks for comments, @mousetail, I edited the post. As for your second comment, the error still appears even outside the venv.

Comment: Do you get the same error if you use the official Python installation from https://python.org?

Comment: Thanks @MattDMo: it seems to work after re-installing from official Python website. As suggested, I am re-creating also all the venvs, to make it work in them as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is the result of a buggy fix to a bug that is triggered when Python is installed without the test module.  The bug appeared in 3.10.8 and 3.12.0a1, released a week ago, and at least in Microsoft Store Python 3.10.2288.0.

Omitting the test module seem to not currently be an option on Mac, so this should not be a problem there.

One fix anywhere is to edit /Lib/idlelib/macosx.py: delete line 7, `from test.support import requires, ResourceDenied`, and replace line 23, `requires('gui')` with `pass`.  This may require admin privileges.

On Windows, rerun the python.org installer, chose Modify, and check the box to install the test suite.

For the Windows store Python, including the test suite may not be an option.  One can, as mentioned in the comments, instead get the python.org installer and install with the test suite.

I don't know what the situation is for *nix.